# Problem in Linear Algebra about finding the smallest positive integer?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb R^{2016}$ over the field of real numbers.
What is the smallest positive integer $k$ for which the following statement is true:

Given any $k$ vectors $v_1, v_2,...,v_k \in  {\mathbb R^{2016}}$, there exist real numbers $a_1, a_2,...,a_k$, not all zero, such that

$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_kv_k=0$ and $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=0$?

Now i know atmost $2016$ vectors are linearly independent in this space, so k must be atleast greater than 2016?

But i am bit confused in exact value?

Is answer $2017$?

Comment: You could try playing with the analogous statement in 2 or 3 dimensions, to see what's happening.

Comment: Yes, the answer is 2017.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom do u know exact reason for this?

Comment: Because it's not true for $2016$, and it is true for $2017$

Comment: because of linear independence it is not true for $2016$, but further?

Answer (score 1):

As $$a_1+.....+a_k=0$$ implies $$-a_k=a_1+.....+a_{k-1}$$ so
$$a_1v_1+.....+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}=(a_1+...+a_{k-1})v_k$$ this implies
$a_1(v_1-v_k)+...+a_{k-1}(v_{k-1}-v_k)=0$.
let $u_i=v_i-v_k$ we have
$a_1u_1+....+a_{k-1}u_{k-1}=0$. As the dimension of the space is 2016, the above equality is always true if $2017 \leq k-1$ (as set of n+1 vectors in a vector space of n dimension is linearly dependent).
This implies $k$ is atleast 2018.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).